# How to ensure that the bot extracts data from an xml/json file?

Tags: c#, botframework, bots

I am trying to build a bot using the BOT Framework that tells jokes when the user feels sad. I have **scraped** some data from a website and made an XML file. I have converted the XML file to JSON. I want the bot to extract data from this JSON file.

Is there any way to do it? Is there a way to add a file to the bot from which it extracts data. I tried building a bot using BOT composer. But could not find a way to extract data from a file or add a file to it.
What I understand is we can make HTTP requests. Should i build an API and then do it?
Is there a way to implement this using bot framework SDK in C#?

Please help. I am really stuck and cannot move forward.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , you can write the custom action(API) to extract data from the file or If the JSON file you can directly read from the file( you can assgin to property to read the value ( Ref here how to read from the JSON file https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/tutorial/tutorial-get-weather?tabs=v2x ))